# How to disable log4j2 Configuration?

Tags: java, log4j2

How can i disable whole configuration?

I tried setting Root Status to off, but then it is not writing into log files and the log files are getting generated as empty files.

I don't want log files to be generated if root status is off... Please suggest if there is any way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a property on your `FileAppender` to create the file on demand.

See `createOnDemand` here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

An example:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingLogFile"
            fileName="logs/rolling.log"
            filePattern="logs/rolling-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log.gz"
            createOnDemand="true">
```

Comment: Getting error: Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile:NullPointerException

Comment: What version of log4j2 are you on? What is the full stack trace? And post your new configuration in your question and we can take a look

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency by excluding spring-boot-starter-logging and my spring boot version is 2.2.4.RELEASE